# How can I put text efficient in sub lists inside a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

I wrote some code to calculate the maximum path sum of a triangle. This is the triangle:

```
    75
   95 64
  17 47 82
 18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
```

So the maximum path sum of this triangle is: `75+95+82+87+82 = 418`

This is my code to calculate it:

```
lst = [[72], 
    [95,64], 
    [17,47,82], 
    [18,35,87,10],
    [20,4,82,47,65]]
something = 1
i = 0
mid = 0
while something != 0:
    for x in lst:
        new = max(lst[i])
        print(new)
        i += 1
        mid += new
    something = 0
print(mid)
```

As you can see I put every item of the triangle down in lists and put the lists in a (head) list. This are not a lot numbers, but what if I have a bigger triangle? To do it manually is  a lot of work. So my question is: **How can I put the numbers from the triangle efficient in sub lists inside a head list?**

Comment: Where do the triangle numbers come from?

Comment: Project Euler, problem 18. I know how to solve it, but I don't know how I can put those numbers in sublists in a list.

Comment: Read a line, use `split()` to turn it into a list, and call `int()` on each list element to make it a list of integers.

Comment: `sublist = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: So your question is how to parse the input string, into a list of lists? Not calculating the results efficiently? Then I would leave out details about the algorithm, and focus on the string and expected output (list of lists).

Comment: Yeah I want to put the string into a list of lists. But the top must be in a list and the layer under that must go in another list. And those lists must go in a head list. Next time I will leave unnecessary details out, but I thought maybe it's better to understand.

Comment: @Barmar, I can't get it done.  Must I put all the numbers from the triangle in another string?  Do you have an example of what you mean? I'm sorry I'm quite new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have input starting with a line containing the number of rows in the triangle, followed by all the numbers on that many rows, read the first number to get the limit in a `range()`. Then use a list comprehension to create the list of sublists.

```
rows = int(input())
lst = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(rows)]
```

For instance, to read your sample triangle, the input would be:

```
5
    75
   95 64
  17 47 82
 18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
```

Comment: Okay, but where do I need to fill in the numbers of my triangle? In the brackets of the input of lst?

Comment: Paste it in as input to the script.